# Jqtouch - link to a div working on PC safari, but not on the iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone, jqtouch

I'm writing a small [web app](http://www.njegox.com/cdminterfejs/jqtouch.html) which is in a pretty early phase, but I'm having trouble with JqTouch transitions. I'm using `<a href="#page2" class="flip" >` as a test on the first link in the horizontal menu bar under the logo. It works perfectly on the PC safari, but does absolutely nothing on the iPhone.

All the tampering with the jqtouch code was to make it fit the screen as I liked it (height:100% in every case, and javascript code (planned, at least) with CSS to resize the page automatically)

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?